# Objects missing in the Interface Builder Object Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios, interface-builder

See the pictures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqOJU.jpg

On the first picture in the library, on the left, are only a fraction of objects that appear in the second picture.

The pictures are of 2 DIFFERENT projects.

If I try to create a new .xib file the problem still persists and only limited objects are available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because the first is an iOS project and the second a Mac OS project.